# Getting column widths for RadGrid on client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, client-side, radgrid

This RadGrid stuff has been a complete nightmare, but I think I'm almost there.

I'm trying to truncate text that's too long and add an ellipsis...

The tricky part is that the user can chose which columns they want to show/hide, so the size of the columns will depend on how many columns are being displayed. My idea is to get the current width of the column and determine how many characters to allow in the cell based on that.

It seems I'm not able to get the widths on the server side if they're not explicitly set. Can this be done on client side?

I've done this, but I'm still getting blanks for the widths:

```
var grid = $find("<%= rgResults.ClientID %>");
var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
var columns = mtv.get_columns();
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
var element = columns[i].get_element();
    alert(element.width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `clientWidth` property instead of just `width`:

```
var grid = $find("<%= rgResults.ClientID %>");
var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
var columns = mtv.get_columns();
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var element = columns[i].get_element();
    alert(element.clientWidth);
}
```